# How long can phd students stay in the US after study

Tags: visas, usa

After the latest change of VISA rules, How **long** can a Ph.D. student stay in the US *after completing the study*?

To be more precise, how **long** a Ph.D. graduate can stay **for finding a job**?

Comment: Your institution's international office should be able to tell you this.